# Intellij IDea, Find in Path can't find content in .iml

Tags: intellij-idea

I use CTRL+SHIFT+F(find in path) in Intellij IDEA, but I can't get the content in *.iml, can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Project Settings <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Click on "File Types" under "IDE Settings"

Check the list of ignored files and folders, and remove `*.iml` from the list.

You can also open Project Structure <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and check "Excluded Roots"

Documentation: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/04/intellij-idea-does-not-show-some-files-know-the-hiding-places/